# Адаптация UI под любые экраны - unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть slider, который находится над передвигающимся объектом. Сделал я это так:

```
 Vector3 ZomPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position);
m_RectTransform(slider).anchoredPosition = new Vector2(ZomPos.x, ZomPos.y);
```

Но в таком случае slider всё равно находится не ровно на объекте, а сдвигается влево, вверх, хоть и передвигается вместе с объектом. Исправил я это тем, что уменьшил ZomPos так, чтобы слайдер стоял ровно надо объектом. Но на других экранах это работает не корректно и не ровно. Как мне сделать так, чтобы slider стоял ровно над объектом при любом экране.

Comment: А как расположен Pivot объекта-слайдера, чью позицию Вы меняете?

Answer (score 0):

```
static public class CanvasHelper {
    static public Canvas Canvas;
    static public Vector2 CanvasSize;

    static CanvasHelper {
        UpdateCanvas();
    }

    static public void UpdateCanvas () {
        Canvas = GameObject.Find("Canvas").GetComponent<Canvas>();
        CanvasSize = canvas.gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta;
    }

    static public Vector2 WorldToCanvasPosition (GameObject obj) {
        Vector2 ViewPos = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(obj.transform.Position);
        ViewPos -= new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);
        return new Vector2(ViewPos.x*CanvasSize.x, ViewPos.y*CanvasSize.y);
    }
}
```